# accessing texture after initial loading in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, caching, textures, sprite, pixi.js

I'm using the pixi.js render engine for my current project in javascript. I'm loading a spritesheet defined in json, using the assetloader. Problem is I need to create sprites or movieclips well after the onComplete event that the assetloader uses, finishes. However the texture cache seems to not be accessible after that point. Here is some of the code below demonstrating the problem I'm coming across.

```
var spriteSheet = [ "test.json" ];
loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader(spriteSheet); // only using the flappy bird sprite sheet as a test 
loader.onComplete = OnAssetsLoaded;
loader.load();

function OnAssetsLoaded() {
    var sprite = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame("someFrame.png"); //this works
}

var sprite2 = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame("someFrame2.png"); //This does not work, tells me "someFrame2" is not in the texture cache
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sprite sheet must be fully loaded before the images get stored in the cache. Once the Sprite sheet has loaded, those assets will exist in the cache until you delete them.

The reason your code above fails is because the line `var sprite2...` executes before the sprite sheet has finished loading.

---

This example will continuously add a new Sprite to the stage every second.

```
//build stage
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

//update renderer
requestAnimFrame( animate );
function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame( animate ); 
    renderer.render(stage);
}

//Flag will prevent Sprites from being created until the Sprite sheet is loaded.
var assetsReadyFlag = false;

//load sprite sheet
var loader = new PIXI.AssetLoader([ "test.json" ]);
loader.onComplete = function(){
    assetsReadyFlag = true;
};
loader.load();

//Add a new bird every second
setInterval( addBird, 1000);
function addBird()
{
    //assets must be loaded before creating sprites
    if(!assetsReadyFlag) return;

    //create Sprite
    var bird = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame("bird.png");
    bird.anchor.x = bird.anchor.y = 0.5;
    bird.x = Math.random() * stage.width;
    bird.y = Math.random() * height;
    stage.addChild(bird);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I'm a bit confused. I had the assumption that ('var sprite2 ..')  was executed after the sprite sheet was loaded because it was executed after ('loader.load()'). Is there something about calling functions from the global scope that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: also I've just figured out how to use `code` markups. Sorry about the horrible formatting above.

Comment: You're correct that the Sprite is created after load() is called, but the image loading process is asynchronous. What's happening is that the Sprite is created immediately after you call load(), but before the texture has finished downloading.

Comment: so how could I get around this.

Comment: Well the correct solution is what you've displayed in your example. You should create the Sprite in the onComplete function. Can you edit your question to show an example of the problems you're running into by doing it this way?

Comment: I will eventually, its been a long time since the question was asked, I eventually found a work around that didn't address the original problem. From what I remember, I was trying to have several different objects with the same image. Because the sprites hold a x and y value, I was trying to create different sprites for each object. Not all the object were created at the beginning of the program, so I couldn't use the OnAssertFinished function for that. However it was a while ago, so I might be confusing the problem a bit. I'll have a look at the old project.

Comment: Hang on, I just remembered. I was trying to write the flappy bird class so that it loaded the sprite in its constructor, and remained self contained. I wanted the gameObject to care of itself so to speak. Now I remember, because I was doing it that way that I didn't wait for OnAssetLoaded. Back then I assumed it was all synchronous. Thank you , you've answered the question.

Comment: The comment about the game object being created at random times, I need to test that because I still think that might be a problem but I'm unsure. I think the loading process might of been aborted because I accessed it too early. Any ideas @Karma

Comment: I'll update my answer to try to explain a good structure to use